# Angular JS: When refreshing the page, all $scope is lost

Tags: angularjs

There are a couple issues I am running into with angularJS when refreshing the page. After user is logged in successfully, if you refresh the page all the $scope is lost. User than has to login again and then log out. Another issue I am having is when the user registers and event they can view all the events in the user dashboard. Inside the user dashboard they have the events inside a "card" with a "delete" button. View "event card code below"

** Event card below **

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col m3 l3" ng-repeat="items in userEvents">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="/images/uploads/{{items.eventImage}}"/>
      <span class="card-title">{{ items.title }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>{{ items.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action"> <!--BREAKING STUFF HERE!-->
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ng     click="updateEvent(items._id)" ui-sref="updateDash">Edit</a>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="deleteEvent(items._id)">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the ng-click="deleteEvent(items.id) is triggered by the code below.

** dashCtrl.js **

```
angular.module("socialApp")

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, dashFactory, infoFactory, $rootScope,      $http, $window) {
 $scope.userEvents = {};
 $scope.id = $rootScope.loggedUser;
 //populates the page with events linked to userID
 dashFactory.getUserEvents($scope.id)
 .then(function(events) {
  $scope.userEvents = events;
  console.log("1st", $scope.userEvents);
  // console.log(events);
});

//deletes event by eventId
$scope.deleteEvent = function(id){
 $scope.eventId = id;
 //console.log($scope.eventId);
 $http.delete('events/deleteEvent/'+id)
  .then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
    $window.location.reload();
  })
}
```

I placed the $window.location.reload(); to refresh the page, so that the deleted "event card" wont show up on the page, but instead of that happening the the page seems to break the event cards and the user $scope is lost. My navbar buttons change to the login and signup buttons as if there is no user logged in.

Please help!!

Comment: how do you get your `userEvents` data ? or via api/service? also please put some `error`

Comment: @kiro112 maybe this update will help?

Comment: what is the datatype of `userEvents` ? Object or array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about how you implement your backend, so this solution is just a general guess. For user login, you should not save the user information in $scope.user, instead you should use session to save any information you want to keep during refresh.

for example create a service like below:

```
angular.module('...')
.service('SessionService', function($window) {
    var service = this;
    var sessionStorage = $window.sessionStorage;

    service.get = function(key) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    };

    service.set = function(key, value) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    };

    service.unset = function(key) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
    };
});
```

in your controller:

```
angular.module('...')
.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, SessionService) {
   $scope.logIn = function(credentials) {
      $http.post('/someUrl', {credentials: credentials}).then(
         function(res) {
            SessionService.set("userId", res.data.id);
            // prefer SessionService.set("userToken", res.data.userToken);     
      });
   }

});
```

and then when you check whether user is logged in or not, you just need to check

```
SessionService.get("userId") is undefined or not
```

you can put it in another service usually called `Authentication`

again, since I don't know how does your authentication work in you backend, so I don't know what data you need to keep in frontend so that even after you refresh the page, you can use the data saved in session storage to query the correct current logged in user from backend again.

after you refresh your page, your angular app will be restore to its initial state, so the idea is simple:

1. after they logged in, you can save some sort of token that can identify the user, then after you refresh the page, you can use the token to make a request to your backend and fetch the logged in user. User information won't be lost.
2. you can choose to save the complete user info in session, so that you don't need to make a request to backend to fetch your user again, and you can delete the user info in session when they log out.

Answer (score 2):

Reloading the page will eliminate all your current scope as you are essentially resetting the page back to its initial state.

If you want to remove the data without resetting scope on your .then call remove the item from the userEvents list.

Comment: its not just that $scope, it seems to be every $scope that was saved up until that point.

Comment: yes refreshing your page completely resets everything - reloading your page is not really how you should update data like that in a spa

Answer (score 0):

> if you refresh the page all the $scope is lost.

the scope is reinitialize on refresh

instead of reloading `$window.location.reload();`
splice the **userEvents** (expecting userEvents[])

```
$scope.deleteEvent = function(id, index){
    $scope.eventId = id;

    $http
        .delete('events/deleteEvent/'+id)
        .then(function(results){
            $window.location.reload();
            $scope.userEvents.splice(index, 1)
        });
}
```

track the index in `ng-repeat="items in userEvents track by $index"`
then add the `$index as parameter` in `ng-click="deleteEvent(items._id, $index)"`